# What is the meaning of 'sputtering' in Ion pumps

Tags: electrons, vacuum

So after reading a few articles this is what I understand:

1. Air enters the pump through diffusion
2. In the pump there is a cloud of electrons between two (grounded) cathodes
3. As soon as an electron hits an air particle, the interaction results is a positively charged cation.
4. This cation hits one of the grounded cathodes which are made of titanium and reacts in such a way that it 'sticks' to the wall.
5. Because of the charged air particle + titanium reaction there occurs some 'sputtering'.

Questions:

1. Is really diffusion the reason why the air molecules enter the pumps?
2. Why is the result of the electron + air particle interaction a **positively** charged cation? I'd expect a negative ion.
3. What is the meaning of this 'sputtering' ?

Sources: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_snzYepQTjI) and [.pdf file](http://home.ufam.edu.br/berti/nanomateriais/aulas%20pptx%20e%20livros/livro/Scanning%20Microscopy%20for%20Nanotechnology/Fundamentals%20of%20Scanning%20Electron%20Microscopy%20(SEM).pdf)

Comment: Sputtering is the knocking off of substrate atoms by an incident energetic particle. In pressure regimes where ion pumps are useful, the mean free path of a gas atom/molecule is much larger than the size of the system- this is often called ballistic transport since the molecule bounces off walls way more than hitting other gas molecules.

Comment: Yes but does the sputtering happen inside the vacuum pump? If so, how do the particles get inside the pump?

Comment: They fly around until they enter that volume.

Comment: So there is nothing the pump does in particular to 'attract' particles. They just enter through standard diffusion. Ok.
Now do you know why such an air particle becomes a positively charged cation after colliding with an electron? I never understood that.

Comment: Once you are out of the flow regime (gas-gas collisions dominate), the pump can't do anything to 'attract' material to it - it can only wait for molecules to enter. As for how energetic electrons can ionize neutral particles, that is a consequence of electron(free)-electron(bound) scattering and energy transfer.